# Unable to send email from Amazon EC2 Server in Java

Tags: java, email, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Trying to send mail from Amazon EC2 server with java code but getting an exception like -

```
Exception in thread "main" Status Code: 403, AWS Request ID: 3e9319ec-bc62-11e1-b2ea-6bde1b4f192c, AWS Error Code: AccessDenied, AWS Error Message: User: arn:aws:iam::696355342546:user/brandzter is not authorized to perform: ses:SendEmail
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:500)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:262)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:166)
at com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient.invoke(AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient.java:447)
at com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient.sendEmail(AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient.java:242)
at brandzter.util.SESExample.SendMail(SESExample.java:46)
at brandzter.util.SESExample.<init>(SESExample.java:31)
at brandzter.util.SESExample.main(SESExample.java:52)
```

Java Result: 1

My credential is ok don't know why I am unable to send email here.
will I need to configure/update any setting in server?

Comment: isn't S3 only storage? maybe in EC2 you can send email.

Comment: You may want to change the title of your post.

Comment: sounds like a permission error for brandzter user. Check its permissions. maybe a misspell somewhere?

Comment: No my website and mail service running on same server. So I think permission is ok.

Comment: @Subin : why I need to use SES?

Comment: so Amazon can charge you for something extra. Joke apart use the right tool for the right job. If you plan on using AWS infrastructure, then use appropriate services. SES seems dedicated to email

Answer (score 11):

You user is not authorized in Identity and Access Management (IAM) to send email to SES.

Error 403 refers to the HTTP code 403 Unauthorized.

The error at the end tells you what permission you are lacking.

> arn:aws:iam::696355342546:user/brandzter is not authorized to perform:
>   ses:SendEmail

Alternately your AWS account may not be signed up for the Simple Email Service, but I doubt that is the problem.

You can add a group to IAM that is allowed just the sendEmail action with the following policy:

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "ses:SendEmail"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Alternately you can give it a policy that allows it to execute any action on SES with:

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "ses:*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Those two code blocks are identical... You probably want the second one to read:  {
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ses:*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Answer (score 6):

In my case i Went to IAm console, choose my user and attach policy AmazonSESFullAccess

Comment: In addition I added AmazonSESFullAccess to the Role of that User.

Comment: I didn't find AmazonSESFullAccess available for the user, but I was able to add it to the group this user belongs. Thanks