# Sending email from Gmail doesn't work on CloudBees

Tags: spring, cloud, jakarta-mail, spam, cloudbees

I am using Apache mail to send emails from my Gmail account, as follows:

```
       HtmlEmail email = new HtmlEmail();
        email.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");
        email.setSmtpPort(465);
        email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("mygmailaccount@mydomain.com", "mypassword"));
        email.setSSLOnConnect(true);
        email.setFrom("no-reply",
                "appName");

    @Async
    public void send(HtmlEmail email) throws EmailException {
        email.send();
    }
```

I am using spring framework to run tasks asynchronously.

This works fine on my local machine, but when trying to run the code from CloudBees, I don't get the email in my inbox although I didn't find anything unusual in the debugs.

Can anyone please advise about this issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the issue was in my code specially in the annotation `@Async` i replaced it with `@Asynchronous` and everything works fine.

Answer (score 3):

There is no network setting stopping outbound connections to any service from CloudBees. However, google may be wary of traffic coming from Amazon hosted IPs - for spam reasons. Amazon also are wary of spam and can control SMTP services.

I expect it is one of these, have you looked up the google docs on why this may be stopped from working?

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15956167/javamail-not-working-on-amazon-ec2 - odd that it works locally, but because it isn't ec2 address, probably why. Need more work at the google end or use a gateway. Spamming is a serious problem and it is kind of by design that it isn't made easy.

Comment: thanks for your efforts, one thing i will try is to check the ip address.